# mmv rename .pdf file in .odt

Tags: linux, unix, rename

I currently have a small problem I would like to convert my .pdf files into .odt files for this I use mmv a program for Linux.

I use the following command to convert all *.pdf files to *.odt files:

> mmv '/root/PDF/*.pdf' '/root/ODT/#1.odt'

Now I have a small problem after the conversion see my files like this

> file.pdf.odt

how can I prevent that the file file.pdf.odt is called ?

I want the ending .pdf to be completely gone and that only stands file.odt

Answer (score 0):

to fix you current problem

```
rename -n s/.pdf// *.odt
```

remove `-n` when result is OK.

I don't have a mmv available, I would try specifying pdf as regexp (regular expression):

```
mmv '/root/PDF/*.[p][d][f]' '/root/ODT/#1.odt'
```

according to man page `*` would go to `#1`, `[p]` to `#2` and so on.